# delete empty pointers to objects stored in a list?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

imagine i have this struct

```
struct datalist {
    int index;
    int number;
};
```

and with that struct we are using, we will be using a list

```
while(Iter != m_SomeList.end());
{
    if(*Iter) 
    {
        //do something

        Iter++;
    }
    else   //Iterator is NULL so can we erase it from the list like so?
    {
        datalist* pAR = *Iter;
        Iter = m_SomeList.erase(Iter);
        delete  pAR;    pAR = NULL;
    }
}
```

so basically the question is, can we delete and erase empty / invalid iterators from the list if they are NULL?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't your test to determine if Iter is null (*Iter) deference a null pointer if Iter is in fact null?

Comment: You seem to have a list of pointers. That's bad in itself, but it also makes the `delete` call entirely pointless.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a list of pointers, you can remove null pointers much more easily:

```
std::list<datalist*> m_SomeList = /* ... */;
m_SomeList.remove(NULL);
```

There's obviously no need to call `delete` since the pointers already don't point anywhere.

On the other hand, it might be more fruitful to combine the erasing logic with the other part of the program (which you aren't showing us) that sets the pointers to NULL.

Comment: Nice - I never knew that `list` had a specialised `remove`!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Iter` is a `list<datalist *>::iterator`, then yes, you can.

You don't need to delete `pAR`, since you know it is null, but doing so is allowed (it has no effect). You've written the loop the right way to handle erase.

(You should always write `++Iter;` not `Iter++;` in C++ though - they are often the same, but occasionally the former is massively more efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

With `<algorithm>` this can be as "simple"<sup>*</sup> as:

```cpp
m_SomeList.erase(
    std::remove_if(m_SomeList.begin(), m_SomeList.end(), [](auto &p){
         return !p;
    }), m_SomeList.end());
```

The lambda can be as complex as you want - you mentioned validity, for example it can remove non-null pointers that point to structs with `index` == 0, or some other criteria, and even `delete` the struct (though its a better idea to use `std::unique_ptr` and let RAII take care of that), but with just a nullability check, this is technically a one liner - though separated here for readability.

`std::remove_if`, unfortunately does not actually remove elements (contrary to what it name implies), instead it moves them to the end of the range and you have to use the "pointer to past last valid element" to actually remove the offending elements - supposedly it is more efficient that way (some containers can perform "erase until the end" in O(1) or something.).

*) for some values of "simple".